# TypeScript return value depending on external constant

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inferred-type

Would it be possible to infer a returned type based on an external varable? Basically, we have different servers with different envs and that region has different enum values for one property. So we have something like this

```js
export enum UKValues = {
  ALL = '*',
  NONE = 'none',
}

export enum USValues = {
  THING = 'that',
}

export type Values = USValues | UKValues;
```

I know I can do something like this

```js
const regionIsUK = (region: string): region is 'UK' => region === 'UK';

export const getValues: (region: 'UK') => UKValues | (region: 'US') => USValues = (region: 'UK' | 'US'): Values => regionIsUk(region) ? UKValues : USValues;
```

Seeing as the value is based on an env, the team doesn't want to have to use `getValues(process.env.REGION)` everywhere they want to use the values.

So! My question is, can I use the infered type on a global scoped varable like `process.env.REGION` in my types to infer the returned type?

```js
export const getValues: process.env.REGION is 'UK' => UKValues | process.env.REGION is 'US' => USValues = () => isRegionUK(process.env.REGION) ? UKValues : USValues;
```

I don't think this is possible because we're depending on the value being set at run time and not compilation time which is annoying. I personally don't mind the first example however it's not my say and the team are prefering this method `const getValues = (): UKValues | USValues => process.env.REGION === 'US' ? USValues : UKValues;` Which I feel is not very specific and could cause cross region values being used because the returned type is not correct and could result in usage as `getValues().ALL` where `ALL` is not a key of `USValues`.

Anyway, let me know what you think of this crazy question. I know most will be questioning why do we need this in the first place and I agree! However we need different returned values based on the region which are defined on return. Like

```js
switch (process.env.REGION) {
  case 'US':
    const result = {
      value: getValues().THING,
    };
  break;
  case 'UK':
    const result = {
      value: something ? getValues().ALL : getValues().NONE,
    };
}
```

And as you can see from the above, we're already using a condition for the `process.env.REGION` so really it would be nicer to remove the method for the enums and use the corresponding enums here however it's opted that we should use diferent enums for each environment which sounds absurd.

Comment: That's not possible. Types are only a compile-time construct and not present in the code at runtime.

Comment: Is there different code between the regions? Just trying to get my head around where the region would be defined when working on the code

Comment: No the code isn't different between regions but the enums are due to business logic. I think I'm just going to push the first option. I didn't think it was possible to do so as it's a computed value not a type. Thanks for looking guys :)